# Do SE sites have question thumbnails? I thought I saw one

Tags: discussion, questions, user-interface

Earlier today, I was on SF and my mouse pointer paused over a question title on the [Questions](http://www.serverfault.com/questions) page. I thought I saw a thumbnail of the question pop up. Later, I could not reproduce.

Does anybody else see this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you weren't on the front page? Items listed there have a tooltip containing the first few lines of the question, while on the Questions page list those are always visible in the list itself.

Comment: I usually work from the Questions page and rarely go to the main page. I guess I didn't realize I was there and didn't know that it had that feature.